# How to wipe a file in bash

Tags: hard-drive, bash

What I'm trying to do is actually zero the drive where a certain file lives on my hard drive.  I know that I could use `> filename` or `dd if=/dev/null of=filename`, or a million other ways to "delete" the file, but I'm wondering if there's a simple way actually write over the bits with 0s (or random data, or whatever).

Comment: Why not just `:> filename` or `cat /dev/null > filename`? Or do you just want to make sure that just that file gets wiped and not extra space? Like maybe if the file was 1GB in size you just want to `:> filename` just that 1GB, correct?

Comment: @JakeGould I want the data off my hard drive. I want it to be as difficult as possible, if someone were to steal my hard drive, for them to retrieve this data, even using data recovery programs. I don't want to simply remove it from the filesystem. That's simple to do with `rm`

Comment: *"I'm wondering if there's a simple way actually write over the bits with 0s"* -- You already answered your own question with `dd if=/dev/null of=filename`.  If that's too long to type every time, then write a script.  BTW if you have a SSD or SDcard, then your effort is futile; you cannot reliably overwrite any data stored in NAND flash because of wear leveling.

Comment: Then this question makes no sense. Do you want to zero free space? What OS are you on? If you use full disk encryption on an OS like macOS then you are completely protected.The drive is encrypted and can’t be decrypted and the only way for someone who stole it to use the machine is to wipe it. Or using Apple tools you can send a command to wipe the disk if it’s missing which effectively tosses encryption keys.

Comment: @JakeGould When you delete a file from an operating system, it doesn't actually write over the data.  That's why you can `rm` a 10GB file in no time at all.  It just removes the references to the data that the filesystem uses to find it.  What I'm trying to do is destroy the actual data. Not simply the references to it.  I want to write over the data on the hard disk bit by bit.

Comment: @sawdust that `dd` command doesn't write over the actual data.  At least it doesn't appear to.  When i `dd if=/dev/null of=filename` for a 10GB `filename` it replaces that 10GB file with a 0B file almost instantly. There's no way the command is overwriting 10GB worth of data that fast.  Also, this is a hard disk, not an SSD

Comment: ewok — May your wishes come true.... https://askubuntu.com/questions/57572/how-to-delete-files-in-secure-manner ... A gift from me to you... lol

Comment: @ewok -- Sorry I didn't read that carefully.  I thought`dd if=/dev/zero of=filename` would work, but that command never stops.  You would need  to supply the `count= ` parameter based on the original filesize in 512byte blocks.